# <choice> not support when writing xsd schema for EMF

Tags: xsd, eclipse-emf

I am writing a schema for EMF to describe general graphs. The problem is that if this is directed graph, then the edge should have properties of src_node and dst_node, otherwise it has node_one and node_two. I tried to use "choice" to have mutally exclusive elements but in EMF it functions the same as "sequence". e.g a similar problem for NodeProperty

```
    <xsd:complexType name="NodeProperty">
            <xsd:choice>
                  <xsd:element name="StringValue" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="IntValue" type="xsd:int"/>
                  <xsd:element name="DoubleValue"  type="xsd:double"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:attribute name="Property" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Another problem in substitutionGroup is that src_node and dst_node are claimed be to unresolved by EMF. The complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsd:simpleType name="GraphType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Directed"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Undirected"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="NodeProperty">
            <xsd:choice>
                  <xsd:element name="StringValue" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element name="IntValue" type="xsd:int"/>
                  <xsd:element name="DoubleValue"  type="xsd:double"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:attribute name="Property" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Node">
            <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                    name="Node" type="lib:NodeProperty"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="NodeName" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="src_node" type="xsd:anyURI" ecore:reference="lib:Node"/>
    <xsd:element name="node_one" type="xsd:anyURI" substitutionGroup="src_node"/>
    <xsd:element name="dst_node" type="xsd:anyURI" ecore:reference="lib:Node"/>
    <xsd:element name="node_two" type="xsd:anyURI" substitutionGroup="dst_node"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="Edge">
    <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="src_node"/>
            <xsd:element ref="dst_node"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="GeneralGraph">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="lib:GraphType"/>
        <xsd:element name="NodeList">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                                    name="Node" type="lib:Node"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>                                                                                                                                                                          
        <xsd:element name="EdgeList">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                                    name="Edge" type="lib:Edge"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>                                                                                                                                                                          
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Substitution groups apply to global elements. So move your elements out of your type and reference to them in the type.

```
<xsd:element name="src_node" type="xsd:anyURI" ecore:reference="lib:Node"/>
<xsd:element name="node_one" type="xsd:anyURI" substitutionGroup="src_node"/>
<xsd:element name="dst_node" type="xsd:anyURI" ecore:reference="lib:Node"/>
<xsd:element name="node_two" type="xsd:anyURI" substitutionGroup="dst_node"/>


<xsd:complexType name="Edge">
        <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="src_node"/>
                <xsd:element ref="dst_node"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Untested.

The idea is that now `node_one` could be used instead `src_node` in `Edge` and `node_two` instead of `node_two`.

Note that type of the substitutable must be derived from the type of the substitution group element. So I used `anyURI` just for example. You'll probably want to rework it.

By the way I generally discourage usage of subsitition groups. Makes your XML unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestion and the substituionGroup is fine. But EMF still claims error src_node and dst_node is unresolved. I added the codes above in my questions. @lexicore

Comment: @Yong Hard to say, maybe because of the namespaces.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, it is working after adding namespace "lib:src_node" but unfortunately in EMF still only src_node and dst_node are shown in the editor. Do you have any idea whether EMF can support substitutionGroup and "choice" or not? Thanks again! @lexicore